# Почему не выводится list во время парсинга

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
URL = 'https://auto.ria.com/newauto/'
HEADERS = {
    
    }
def get_html(url,params= None):
    r = requests.get(url,headers = HEADERS, params = params)
    return r
def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
    items = soup.find_all('a', class_='unlink rotator5_item')
    price = soup.find_all('span',class_='price')
    cars = []
    for item in items:
        cars.append({
            'title':item.find('li',class_='title').get_text()
            })
    print(cars)
def parse():
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        print("Все круто")
        get_content(html.text)
    else:
        print("Все плохо,давай по новой Миша")
```

Answer (score 0):

На верное не хватает

```
parse()
```

или

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parse()
```